# How to use data files of sub-directories and perform iterative operation in python

Tags: python, loops, directory, path, operating-system

I have my jupyter notebook (python script) in current directory. In current directory, I have two subfolders, namely `a` and `b`. In both directories `a` and `b` I have equal number of `.dat` files with same names. For example, directory `a` contains files, namely `x1-x1-val_1`, `x1-x1-val_5`, `x1-x1-val_11`...`x1-x1-val_86` and `x1-x2-val_1`, `x1-x2-val_5`, `x1-x2-val_11`...`x1-x2-val_86`, i.e. values are in `range(1,90,5)`. Likewise I have files in directory `b`.

I want to use my python script to access files in `a` and `b` to perform iterative operations on `.dat` files. My present code works only if I keep files of directory `a` or `b` in current directory. For example, my script uses following function.

```
def get_info(test):     
    my_dict = {'test':test}   
    c = []    
    
    for i in range(1,90,5):    
        x_val = 'x_val_'+test+'-val_'+str(i)
        y_val = 'y_val_'+test+'-val_'+str(i)
        
        my_dict[x_val],my_dict[y_val]= np.loadtxt(test+'-val_'+str(i)+'.dat'
                                                        ,usecols= (1,2),unpack=True)
        dw = compute_yy(my_dict[x_val],my_dict[y_val],test)
        c.append(dw)
    
    my_dict.update({test+'_c'+:np.array(c)})

    return my_dict
```

I call `get_info()` by using following:

```
tests = ['x1-x1', 'x1-x2']

new_dict = {}
for i in tests:
     new_dict.update({i:get_info(i)})
```

How can I use my code to access files in either directory `a` and/or `b`? I know its about providing correct path, but I am unsure how can I do so. One way I thought is following;

```
ext = '.dat'
for files in os.listdir(path_to_dir):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        print(files)   # do operations
```

Alternative could be to make use of `os.path.join()`. However, I am unable to solve it such that I can use same python script (with minimum changes perhaps) that can use files and iterate on them which are in subfolders `a` and `b`. Thanks for your feedback in advance!

Comment: You can keep your Python script in the parent directory of `a` and `b`. Call the function defined by changing the current working directory (cwd) to `a`, then change cwd to parent directory and finally cwd to`b` to call the function again. The current working directory can be changed using `os.chdir()`.

Comment: you can use folder name when you open `loadtxt("a/filename")` and `loadtxt("b/filename")`

Comment: do you want to run `get_info()` separatelly on files in `a` and separatelly on files in `b` ? You could define function as `def get_info(test, folder):` and later use `loadtxt( folder + "/" + ...)` and later run as `get_info(i, "a")`, `get_info(i, "b")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run `get_info()` on every folder separatelly then you have two methods:

**First:** described by @medium-dimensional in comment

You can use `os.chdir(folder)` to change `Current Working Directory`. And then code will run with files in this folder

You can see current working directory with `print( os.getcwd() )`

```
os.chdir("a")
get_info(i)
os.chdir("..") # move back to parent folder

os.chdir("b")
get_info(i)
os.chdir("..") # move back to parent folder
```

`chdir()` (similar to command `cd` in console) can use relative path (`r"a"`) full path (`r"C:\full\path\to\a"`) and `..` to move to parent folder (`r"a\..\b"`)

If files can be in nested folders then `..` may not go back you can use `getcwd()`

```
cwd = os.getcwd()

os.chdir("folder1/folder2/a")
get_info(i)
os.chdir(cwd) # move back to previous folder

os.chdir("folder1/folder2/b")
get_info(i)
os.chdir(cwd) # move back to previous folder
```

### (BTW: in console on Linux you can use `cd -` to move back to previous folder)

**Second:** use folder when you open file

Every command which gets filename can also get path with `folder\filename` (it can be relative path, full path, and path with `..`) like

- `r"a\filename.dat"`
- `r"C:\full\path\to\b\filename.dat"`
- `r"a\..\b\filename.dat"`

So you could define function with extra option `folder`

```
def get_info(text, folder):
```

and use this folder when you read file

```
loadtxt(folder + r'\' + test+'-val_'+str(i)+'.dat', ...)
```

or more readable with `f-string`

```
loadtxt(rf'{folder}\{test}-val_{i}.dat', ...)
```

And later you run it as

```
get_info(i, "a")

get_info(i, "b")
```